# Java cardlayout, KeyListener stops working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, cardlayout

I have `KeyListener` in my `CardLayout`.

```
KeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener();
addKeyListener(listener);
setFocusable(true);
```

And it works just fine. The problem is when I exit this `JPanel` from my main screen manager:

```
private CardLayout cl;
cl.show(cardPanel, "1");
```

and comes back to it the `KeyListener` stops working. How can I evoke the `KeyListener` again, when the `JPanel` is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListeners` have issues with focus, while you have set the component focusable, you've not `requestFocusInWindow` when the view has changed back.

Instead, use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which have greater focus handling control